# In Office 2019, Open Access Database for SQL-Queries with legacy Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

In Office 2019, I have legacy-code in Excel VBA accessing an MDB-file (=Access Database).

In the previous versions this was working.

```vb
Sub min_example()
    Dim myDB As DAO.Database, query As DAO.Recordset
    Dim szSQL$
    Set myDB = OpenDatabase("C:\temp\test.mdb")
  
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable;"
    Set query = dbKatrin.OpenRecordset(szSQL)
End Sub
```

When the command `Set myDB...` is to be executed I get the following error:

> Run-time error 80040154
> Class not registered

I found how to get tables filled but I prefer only query-results taken from the Access file.
If there is some other engine instead of JET then I am easy with it as long as there is documentation.

Answer (score 1):

To make the work-around that I found a bit more readable for others that migh have the same issue on re-using legacy code for Access-databases, here something that works for me with the same results as the old code:

```
Sub minTest_workaround()
  'Creating objects of Connection and Recordset
  Dim dbmyDBConn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim dbQuery As New ADODB.Recordset

  Dim szDB_Path$, szProvider$, szConnString$
  Dim szSQL$

  'Declaring fully qualified name of database. Change it with your database's location and name.
  szDB_Path = "C:\temp\test.mdb"
  'This is the connection provider.
  szProvider = "Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;"
  'This is the connection string that you will require when opening the the connection.
  szConnString = "Provider=" & szProvider & "Data Source=" & szDB_Path
  'opening the connection
  dbmyDBConn.Open szConnString

  'the query I want to run on the database.
  szSQL = "SELECT * from myTable;"
  'running the query on the open connection. It will get all the data in the rec object.
  dbQuery.Open szSQL, dbmyDBConn
  If (dbQuery.RecordCount <> 0) Then
    Do While Not dbQuery.EOF
      Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).Value2 = dbQuery.Fields(0).Value
      dbQuery.MoveNext
    Loop
  End If
  'closing the connections
  dbQuery.Close
  dbmyDBConn.Close
End Sub
```

Cheers
ye_ol_man

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set a Reference to either:

*Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library*  - or:

*Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library*

And where does *dbKatrin* come from? Try:

```vb
Sub min_example()
    
    Dim myDB As DAO.Database, query As DAO.Recordset
    Dim szSQL$
    Set myDB = OpenDatabase("C:\temp\test.mdb")
    
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable;"
    Set query = myDB.OpenRecordset(szSQL)
    
End Sub
```

Else, try a *repair* of the Office installation:

[Microsoft Access "Class Not Registered" Run-time Error '-2147221164 (80040154)'](https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Errors/class_not_registered/index.htm)

Comment: Hello Gustav,
I have references both to the MS Office 16.0 Access Object Library and the DAO 3.6 Object Library active. The dbKatrin was a typo, the myDB is correct. However I don't even get that far.

Comment: Hello Gustav, 
the repair unfortunately did not help, however I found a way to switch from DAO to ADO the following way:
`code`<br/> instead of <br/>Dim dbmyDB As DAO.Database, query As DAO.Recordset<br/>I use now<br/>Dim dbmyConn As New ADODB.Connection<br/>Dim dbQuery As New ADODB.Recordset

Comment: trying again with the comment...Instead of
`Dim dbmyDB As DAO.Database, query As DAO.Recordset`I use now`Dim dbmyConn As New ADODB.Connection Dim dbQuery As New ADODB.Recordset`